# Storing family relationships in neo4j DB by using laravel php framework

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, neo4j

I've written a simple web app in laravel php framework to store family relationships. Here is the code:
**`relationship.blade.php`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Form!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">

        div {
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            width: 713px;
            /* margin-right: 20px; */
            /* padding-right: 20px; */
            left: 190px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 478px;">Enter your name and relationship with other people in the family</p>
<div class="formController">

    {{ Form::open() }}

        {{ Form::token() }}

        {{ Form::textField('username', 'Name:') }}

        {{ Form::label('text', 'Relationship: '); }} 

        {{ Form::select('size', array('F' => 'Father', 'M' => 'Mother', 'S' => 'Sister', 'B' => 'Brother'), 'S'); }} <br>

        {{ Form::submit('Click Me!'); }}

    {{ Form::close() }}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`Routes.php`**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/relationship', function()
{
    return View::make('relationship');
});
```

**`RelationshipController.php`**

```
<?php

class RelationshipController extends BaseController {

    public function showRelation()
    {
        return View::make('Relationship');
    }

}
```

**`Relationship.php`** ( This is the model where I've written code to push form data to neo4j DB )

```
<?php

class Duck extends NeoEloquent {

    //protected $fillable = array('name', '', 'password');

    public function index($name, $options) {

        $formData = Neo4j::makeNode();
        $formData->setProperty('name',$name)
        ->setProperty('relationship',$options)
        ->save();

    }

}
```

But when I click on `submit` button in the form, it displays an error message like, `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` How can I fix it?  And data doesn't get stored in neo4j DB.

Comment: What is written in the logs of laravel ?

Comment: Here is laravel log: http://pastebin.com/wa1zkSLs

Comment: Did you understand what the errors in your logs are saying ? Please don't take my words are offensive, I welcome everybody to use neo4j and of course php because it is my favorite language, but almost all your last questions on SO are showing a lack of knowledge of the application level stack you are using. There was none question showing a Neo4j problem stuff. I recommend that maybe you go a bit deeper in the Laravel documentation and in the meantime if you want to familiarize with Neo4j you can always use the Neo4j browser or the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.
I added rote for posting:
**`Code:`**

```
Route::post('relationship', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{

    // create the validation rules ------------------------
    $rules = array(
            'name'        => 'required',                        // just a normal required validation
            'options'     => 'required|options|unique:relationship',    // required and must be unique in the ducks table
    );

    // create custom validation messages ------------------
    $messages = array(
            'required' => 'The :attribute is really really really important.',
            'same'  => 'The :others must match.'
    );

    // do the validation ----------------------------------
    // validate against the inputs from our form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

    // check if the validator failed -----------------------
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // redirect our user back with error messages
        $messages = $validator->messages();

        // also redirect them back with old inputs so they dont have to fill out the form again
        // but we wont redirect them with the password they entered

        return Redirect::to('relationship')
        ->withErrors($validator);

    } else {
        // validation successful ---------------------------

        $relationship = new Relationship;
        $relationship->name     = Input::get('name');
        $relationship->options    = Input::get('options');
//      $duck->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        $relationship->save();

        // redirect ----------------------------------------
        return Redirect::to('relationship')
        ->with('messages', 'Hooray!');

    }

}));
```